# Horizontal Text Slider WIth Hidden Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to create a **pure** javascript/css vertical text slider with hidden overflow with some animations

But I am having trouble trying to figure it out. I've included an image representation of what I am trying to achieve.

**Requirements**

- The text should be an inline-block
- Text Overflow should be hidden
- Animated

Thanks for taking the time, it is extremely appreciated.

```css
span {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
Start <span>Promatia</span>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you attempted to alter the width of the text container and experimented with overflows? Have you looked at CSS animations and tried to create some basic ones?

Comment: I've tried to setTimeout but i'm not sure how to approach it. Not sure how to make the animation transitions work with an ease-in-out @Dan

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this :

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("span").style.width = "150px";
},500);
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("span").style.width = "0px";
},2000);
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "A New Country";
},2300);
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("span").style.width = "240px";
},2500);
```

```css
span {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  transition-duration:0.3s;
  height:40px;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<span id="span">Promatia</span>
```

And also, you can do it with CSS only using `@keyframes` and `:before` , it will be better.

This is just a concept.

Answer (score 1):

**Run the snippet for live version**

```js
let items = ['Promatia', 'A New Country', 'A New Society', 'A New City', 'A New Life']
let index = 0
let textEl = document.getElementById('text')
let wrapperEl = document.getElementById('wrapper')

async function enlargeBox(){
  if(index + 1 > items.length) index = 0
  textEl.innerHTML = items[index++]
  wrapperEl.style.width = textEl.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px'
}

async function shrinkBox(){
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500))
  wrapperEl.style.width = '0px'
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 250) ) //use same length as animation
}

enlargeBox().then(async ()=>{
  while (true) {
     await shrinkBox()
     await enlargeBox()
  }
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
    transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
    width: 0px;
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.switcher {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    
body {
   background: black;
   color: white;
   font: 3em bold;
}
```

```html
start <div id="wrapper"><span id="text" class="switcher"></span></div>
```